# binary file execution error (Assembly - linux)

Tags: linux, assembly, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My main operating system Windows. I installed Ubuntu as windows subsystem. I am using nasm.

Assembly Code:

```
section .text
      global _start

_start:
      move eax,1
      move ebx,0
      int 0x80
```

I compiled it like this

```
----> nasm -f elf FILENAME.asm
----> ls

FILENAME.asm    FILENAME.o

---> ld -m elf_i386 FILENAME.o -o OUTFILE
---> ls

FILENAME.asm   FILENAME.o   OUTFILE
```

When I run OUTFILE, I get an error like this:

```
-bash: ./OUTFILE: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Can you help me?

Comment: WSL cannot execute 32 bit programs.  either use real Ubuntu or switch to amd64 assembly.